# Installing Tuleap on SunOS from sources

Tags: solaris, tuleap

I am trying to install Tuleap in a corporate server. `uname -a` gives me the following:

> SunOS xxxx 5.9 Generic_Virtual sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise

Could you indicate a procedure I could follow to install Tuleap from the sources?

Answer (score 0):

Tuleap works on CentOS 5 and 6. There is a beta version for debian. I think the only guaranteed way to make it work on SunOS is via something like virtualBox or lxc.